# Speeding up duplicating of rows in Pandas groupby?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a very large data frame (hundreds of millions of rows). There are two group ID's, `group_id_1` and `group_id_2`. The data frame looks like this:

```
group_id_1    group_id_2    value1    time
1             2             45        1
1             2             49        2
1             4             95        1
1             4             55        2
2             2             44        1
2             4             88        1
2             4             90        2
```

For each `group_id_1` x `group_id_2` combo, I need to duplicate the row with the latest time, and increment the time by one. In other words, my table should look like:

```
group_id_1    group_id_2    value1    time
1             2             45        1
1             2             49        2
1             2             49        3
1             4             95        1
1             4             55        2
1             4             55        3
2             2             44        1
2             2             44        2
2             4             88        1
2             4             90        2
2             4             90        3
```

Right now, I am doing:

```
for name, group in df.groupby(['group_id_1', 'group_id_2']):
    last, = group.sort_values(by='time').tail(1)['time'].values
    temp = group[group['time']==last]
    temp.loc[:, 'time'] = last + 1
    group = group.append(temp)
```

This is insanely inefficient. If I put the above code into a function, and use the `.apply()` method with the `groupby` object, it also takes an enormous amount of time.

How do I speed this process up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregate [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html), add time by [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html) and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to original:

```
df1 = df.sort_values(by='time').groupby(['group_id_1', 'group_id_2']).last().reset_index()
df1.time = df1.time.add(1)
print (df1)
   group_id_1  group_id_2  value1  time
0           1           2      49     3
1           1           4      55     3
2           2           2      44     2
3           2           4      90     3

df = pd.concat([df,df1])
df = df.sort_values(['group_id_1','group_id_2']).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    group_id_1  group_id_2  value1  time
0            1           2      45     1
1            1           2      49     2
2            1           2      49     3
3            1           4      95     1
4            1           4      55     2
5            1           4      55     3
6            2           2      44     1
7            2           2      44     2
8            2           4      88     1
9            2           4      90     2
10           2           4      90     3
```

Comment: but how does it perform on huge datasets ?

Comment: OP will tell us

Comment: I believe that adding `sort=False` will speed up the `groupby` operation. It certainly does so when groups are long, random strings.

Comment: Yes, it can be faster.

Comment: I'm not back with my data yet, but once I am I will definitely time the different methods.

Comment: Took 2.8 seconds on 2 million rows, significantly faster than what I was doing (I didn't even wait for my method to finish because it was taking so long).

Answer (score 3):

**First**, sort the dataframe by time (this should be more efficient than sorting each group by time):

```
df = df.sort_values('time')
```

**Second**, get the last row in each group (without sorting the groups to improve performance):

```
last = df.groupby(['group_id_1', 'group_id_2'], sort=False).last()
```

**Third**, increment the time:

```
last['time'] = last['time'] + 1
```

**Fourth**, concatenate:

```
df = pd.concat([df, last])
```

**Fifth**, sort back to the original order:

```
df = df.sort_values(['group_id_1', 'group_id_2'])
```

Explanation: concatenating and then sorting will be much faster than inserting rows one by one.

Comment: This works great too, I think the same method as @jezrael. Since he answered first I'll mark his as answered, but I especially appreciate the formatting of yours